# Java string - replace multiple spaces by one and then split string into array based on space

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Suppose I have a string

```
s ="[    2323.2323 232.3232 0.2 0.3 3232]"
```

I want to split it into an array of strings by space delimiter. I also want to preserve a single space between values and ignore the multiple space.

What would be the regular expression to do this?

Comment: preserve the single space where ?

Comment: you can try?....also specify your required output for the given input..

Comment: The question makes no sense. If you split by space delimiter, all the spaces will be gone. Can you rephrase the question, and give a good input/output example? You can use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16739012/edit) button below your question.

Comment: If you want to split into an array, why do you still need the space ? Is the space required only when you print out the resulting array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get rid of multiple spaces:

```
String after = before.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Then Split the String up into your array using the split method

Comment: `split` uses regex, so `replaceAll` isn't needed: `string = string.trim().split(" +");`

Comment: +1 for a another good solution but, I was simply trying to answer the question that was asked